# How to read brower's stored values of login email and password

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a webform application which starts with ASP classic that runs a database query before window.onload and then show the form. If the form display a previous stored email and password I want to use them within the ASP query, but these are available only after form display. My question is if it possible and how to access and read the stored email and password before the form is loaded?

Comment: Could you please show the code you've come up with so far?  Thanks.

Comment: Currently my code deals with processing the form data. The code/trick I'm looking for  is related to item such as   <input type="email".. > which is part of a Form.  My intention is to display the user name base on querying his/her email and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a password input element, then no, it is not possible to read this from javascript. This would break the security model of the browser. (It is far from clear what you are describing here)

Comment: Sorry, to (try) put it simple: How to reveal saved browser password and email with JavaScript.